# Failed to read Region from AWSConfiguration

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have started using DynamoDB, I have created a project on Mobile Hub and pasted the awsconfiguration.json inside Android App.
I want to create an Item inside UserDetails table.
I am using following code to instantiate AWS and DynamoDB services.

```
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new AWSStartupHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {

            // Obtain the reference to the AWSCredentialsProvider and AWSConfiguration objects
            credentialsProvider = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider();
            configuration = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration();

            // Add code to instantiate a AmazonDynamoDBClient
            AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);

            dynamoDBMapper = DynamoDBMapper.builder()
                    .dynamoDBClient(dynamoDBClient)
                    .awsConfiguration(configuration)
                    .build();  //This line is causing exception

            // Use IdentityManager#getUserID to fetch the identity id.
            IdentityManager.getDefaultIdentityManager().getUserID(new IdentityHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onIdentityId(String identityId) {
                    Log.d("YourMainActivity", "Identity ID = " + identityId);

                    // Use IdentityManager#getCachedUserID to
                    //  fetch the locally cached identity id.
                    final String cachedIdentityId =
                            IdentityManager.getDefaultIdentityManager().getCachedUserID();
                }

                @Override
                public void handleError(Exception exception) {
                    Log.d("YourMainActivity", "Error in retrieving the identity" + exception);
                }
            });
        }
    }).execute();
```

And the exception I am getting is:

```
    07-10 15:46:55.466 20392-20392/com.userdetails.userdetails E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.userdetails.userdetails, PID: 20392
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to read Region from AWSConfiguration please check your setup or awsconfiguration.json file
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$Builder.build(DynamoDBMapper.java:328)
        at com.userdetails.userdetails.MainActivity$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:48)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$2.onComplete(AWSMobileClient.java:164)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$4.run(IdentityManager.java:635)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
```

I tried changing awsconfiguration.json file with the updated one, still I am getting same exception.

Comment: Can you paste the complete stack trace?

Comment: @Karthikeyan These are only error logs I am getting when onComplete() method runs.

Comment: Can you add the following to awsconfiguration.json?                                               "DynamoDBObjectMapper" : {
        "Default" : {
            "Region" : "DYNAMODB-REGION"
        } 
    }

Comment: @Karthikeyan Your suggestion is absolutely correct even I did this fix 2-3 days ago, Will post that as an answer here.

Comment: I thought you would provide me a different solution, Also if you are from AWS, pls get these things corrected so that developers should not face these silly errors.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused. We will update this in our documentation. Question: Are you onboarding with AWS Mobile Hub?

Comment: @Karthikeyan Yes, Anything you want to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following snippet to awsconfiguration.json file.

```
"DynamoDBObjectMapper" : {
    "Default" : {
        "Region" : "DYNAMODB-REGION"
    } 
}
```